# Adding Items From A List<ListViewItem>

Tags: c#, list, listview

Sorry for my bad English :(.

Hi, how do I add the items to a ListView that I've put in a List?

I've tried this:

```
listView1.Items.Add(pluginContainer);
```

But this doesn't seem to work :(.

I can't make a foreach loop because then it will take like 10 seconds for the ListView to be filled (I'm talking about 5000+ items).

This fixed it:

```
listView1.Items.AddRange(pluginContainer.ToArray());
```

Comment: A listview is a very bad UI element to interact with 5000 items. Consider virtualized / paged UI instead.

Comment: what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: I'm trying to load a list of plugins listed here: bukget.org/api/plugins I use a `ListView` because it looks organized and I can easily interact with the items.

Comment: can you show some more code and also explain what is the problem or error you are running into?

Comment: @Mayank I download the list via JSON.Net and put it in a `List<string>`, after that I make a `ListViewItem` and then for every string I want to make a `ListViewItem` so I can add that to my `ListView`. This works, however it's very slow. I've added some code.

Comment: Can you show what the items look like? In general you need to convert each item as an array of strings, each corresponding to a different column in the list view when used with detailed view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the items in your list are all of type ListViewItem, you can use [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfzz668s.aspx). If they're not, you're going to have to either make ListViewItems out of them, or use a for loop.

In either case, you should strive to improve the performance of a ListView during addition of items, by first calling [SuspendLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) on it. After you've added all its items, call [ResumeLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout.aspx).

Comment: I've tried `AddRange` like this: `listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { pluginContainer });` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `SuspendLayout` also doesn't seem to help :(.

Comment: Can you be more specific? When you say "It doesn't work", what, exactly, do you mean? What happens? What exceptions are thrown? What syntax error, if any, occurs?

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'` is what I get when I do: `listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { pluginContainer });`

Comment: Nvm I got it! It was the AddRange, I did it wrong, now it works. Posting th esolution in my post.

Comment: Suspend/ResumeLayout have no effect on a ListView.  You might have meant Begin/EndUpdate() but that's unnecessary when you use AddRange().

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I meant the Begin/EndUpdate().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public enum State
{
    AL, GA, FL, SC, TN, MI
}

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    // Converts properties to string array
    public string[] ToListViewItem()
    {
        return new string[] {
            ID.ToString("00000"),
            Name,
            State.ToString() };
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Setup list view column headings and widths
        listView1.Columns.Add("ID", 48);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 300);
        listView1.Columns.Add("State", 48);
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        // Create a list
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
        // Fill in some data
        list.Add(new Person() { ID=1001, Name="John", State=State.TN });
        list.Add(new Person() { ID=1002, Name="Roger", State=State.AL });
        list.Add(new Person() { ID=1003, Name="Samantha", State=State.FL});
        list.Add(new Person() { ID=1004, Name="Kara", State=State.MI});

        // Fill in ListView from list
        PopulateListView(list);
    }

    void PopulateListView(List<Person> list)
    {
        listView1.SuspendLayout();
        for(int i=0; i<list.Count; i++)
        {
            // create a list view item
            var lvi = new ListViewItem(list[i].ToListViewItem());
            // assign class reference to lvi Tag for later use
            lvi.Tag = list[i];
            // add to list view
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
        //This adjust the width of 1st column to fit data.
        listView1.AutoResizeColumn(0, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
        listView1.ResumeLayout();
    }
}
```

[image: ListView Example]